# Model Binding with Internal List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have two models as follows:

```
public class MyMainClass
{
    internal List<MyOtherClass> {get; set;}
    public int SomeValue {get; set;}
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public int SomeOtherValue {get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to bind `MyMainClass` as a parameter in my controller with the internal property being populated. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyMainClass myMainClass)
```

From my reading, it seems that in order to bind an internal property I need to create my own model binder, which I've done below:

```
public class MyOtherClassBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        MyOtherClass model = (MyOtherClass) (bindingContext.Model ?? new MyOtherClass());

        model.SomeOtherValue = GetValue<int>(bindingContext, nameof(MyOtherClass.SomeOtherValue));
        model.ColumnConfigurations = GetValue<List<WebTableColumnConfiguration>>(bindingContext, nameof(WebTableConfiguration.ColumnConfigurations));
        return model;
    }

    private T GetValue<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        return (T)result.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
    }
}

public class MyMainClassBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        MyMainClass model = (MyMainClass) (bindingContext.Model ?? new MyMainClass());

        model.SomeValue = GetValue<int>(bindingContext, nameof(MyMainClass.SomeValue));
        model.Items = GetValue<List<MyOtherClass>>(bindingContext, nameof(MyMainClass.Items));

        return model;
    }

    private T GetValue<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        return (T)result.ConvertTo(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

However, my model binder fails when I try to get the value for `Items`, the `ValueProviderResult` is null, presumably because it can't find the value. In the debugger if I check the `ValueProvider` and drill down through the `FormValueProvider` I can see that there are values for the `Items` list:

```
{[items[0][SomeOtherValue], System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider+ValueProviderResultPlaceholder]}
{[items[1][SomeOtherValue], System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider+ValueProviderResultPlaceholder]}
```

How can I get my custom model binder to properly bind my list of custom items? Is this even the right approach for this?

I'm sure if I made the property `public` instead of `internal` it would work without a custom model binder but these classes will be part of a library where the consuming application would subclass from `MyMainClass` and I don't want some of my properties exposed.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, custom model binder for this case is a overkill, in my opinion.

If you don't want to expose some properties from your `internal MyOtherClass`, why don't you just create a Dto model for example `MyOtherClassDto`, which will only expose those properties that have to be accessible from the API

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I'm not sure how that would work since I need the internal property set outside the API via the model binder